# Split Angular2 app onto chunks with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

What if I want to build angular2 project which is written in Typescript, but I don't want to bundle all into one bundle. I want to bundle vendors into vendor.bundle.js and other stuff keep in the same shape as project structure.

Base structure:

```
app/
    main-module/
        main-module.ts
        main-module.html
        main-module.css
    page-module/
        page-module.ts
        page-module.html
        page-module.css
   main.ts
   vendor.ts
```

Structure we want to have:

```
app/
    main-module/
        main-module.js
        main-module.html
        main-module.css
    page-module/
        page-module.js
        page-module.html
        page-module.css
    main.js
    vendor.bundle.js
```

In the index.html we do

```
<script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="main-module.js"></script>
<script src="page-module.js"></script>
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + '/app',

entry: {
    'vendor': './vendor',
    'main': './main'
},

stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
},

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/js'),
    publicPath: 'js/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },

        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
        },

        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
            // exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor']
    })
]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack require en entry point, without entry point it will throw error. if you just want to compile you ts files then you don't need webpack pr systemjs you can simply use typescript compiler and you will keep the same file structure. Webpack is much more.

### What is webpack

webpack is a module bundler.

webpack takes modules with dependencies and generates static assets representing those modules.

> NOTE:- If you want a dist folder with sam file structure but without ts files then you may use tools like gulp for this approach.

i hope it helps. happy coding

Comment: I have some dependencies that uses CommonJS. For example lot's of stuff in node_modules, how am I going to manage it on SystemJS?

Comment: please explain bit more what kind of dependencies?  and how do you want to manage them?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I'm not quite sure how does SystemJS work. But I have to deal with Angular, RxJS modules. I don't want to put the whole node_modules  folder into production. Instead I wanted to have vendor.bunle.js with Angular, RxJS and other stuff and base app js files. I've updated app structure, look above.

Comment: Specifying multiple entry points and using 1 commons chunk seems to be the most used way of splitting code. But how to split Angular app code onto chunks?